# Случайная строка из БД в Ruby on Rails

Tags: база-данных, строки, ruby-on-rails

Есть Controller:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController

  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "admin", password: "123", except: [:new]

  def index
    @answers = Answer.all
  end

  def new
    @answer = Answer.new
  end

  def create
    @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)
    if @answer.save
        flash[:notice] = "Спасибо!"
        redirect_to new_answer_path
    else
        flash[:alert] = "Уууууупс...ошибка"
        redirect_to new_answer_path
    end    
  end

  def destroy
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
    @answer.destroy
    redirect_to answers_path
  end

  def randomaizer
    @randomizer = Answer.where(params[:title]).sample
  end

  private
    def answer_params
      params.require(:answer).permit(:title)
    end
end
```

Методом `randomaizer` пытаюсь вывести случайную строку из БД, в модели все примитивно, только запись одного поля `title`

На всякий случай прикрепляю `Routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'game#index'
  resources :answers, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy]
  get 'game(/randomaizer)', to: 'answers#randomaizer'

end
```

Ну и, соответственно, кидаю вот что-то такое во вьюху: `<% @randomaizer.title %>`

Только вот проблема в том, что и ошибок нет, но и экран белый -- где чего не хватает?

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу логи сервера, пожалуйста. `Answer.where(params[:title]).sample` - неверно, должно быть `Answer.where(title: params[:title]).sample`

Comment: При изменении на ваш вариант теперь ошибка появилась (на вьюху ругается): ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass):
    2:  <% @randomaizer.title %>  
app/views/answers/randomaizer.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_answers_randomaizer_html_erb__2751549794974185924_47458015760160'
Started GET "/game/randomaizer" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-03-25 14:30:57 +0300
Processing by AnswersController#randomaizer as HTML
  Answer Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."title" IS NULL

Comment: Это говорит о том, что в @randomaizer у вас пусто

Comment: А пусто потому, что `WHERE "answers"."title" IS NULL ` - в параметрах тоже пусто, и params[:title] пустой

Comment: Как вы передаёте параметры в экшн randomaizer?

Comment: По всякому пробовал и @randomaizer = Answer.all ; и = Answer.find(params[:title]) ; и = Answer.find(params[:id]) - ничего из этого не работает.

Comment: А чего вы хотите добиться? И ещё раз повторю вопрос - как вы передаёте параметр title в этот экшн? Чтобы `params[:title]` что-то содержало, это что-то туда нужно передать.

Comment: моя задача - этим экшеном вывести случайную строку из БД. Не сочтите тупым, но я еще не до конца понимаю как это правильно сделать) т.к. только начинаю. И думал, если передать = Answer.all , то это сделает запрос на выгрузку всех строк, а потом с помощью where...sample я получаю случайную

Comment: Всё верно, но чтобы where сработало, нужно что-то положить в параметры. Это должны выглядеть примерно как `randomizer_path(title: 'Some title')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наконец-то нашлось решение, и довольно простое!
Есть `gem ' randumb '` (https://github.com/spilliton/randumb).
Добавил его, установил, и нужный мне функционал стал доступен всего одной строкой:

```
def randomaizer
    @randomaizer = Answer.order_by_rand.limit(1).all
end
```

А во вьюхе так:

```
<% @randomaizer.each do |rnd| %>
<span>
    <%= rnd.title %>
</span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Это решается гораздо проще и без гема: `Answer.order("RANDOM()").first` или `Answer.order("RANDOM()").limit(5)`, если нужно больше одной записи